# Is there a function like isin() in pandas that accepts conditional statements instead of a value to print out highly correlated variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

Say I have a correlation matrix dataframe like

```
  A    B   C
A 1.0  0.8 0.6

B 0.8  1.0 0.1

C 0.6  0.1 1.0
```

I want to return the indexes where the values are `>0.7`. I figured out that in the case where I was looking for values that are 0.8 exactly, I would be using the isin() function to find the row and iterate over the columns (As described here : https://thispointer.com/python-find-indexes-of-an-element-in-pandas-dataframe/ ). However since I want values greater than a certain number instead of a specific value, I'm not sure which alternative can be used to the `isin()` function. Any suggestions? If there is a better way to do this, I would like to know.

(P.S. I have saved the correlation matrix generated via df.corr() as a Dataframe `ds`)

Answer (score 3):

I use the following method daily to keep the correlations which are higher than a certain value, using `DataFrame.where` and `DataFrame.stack`, then I list the index:

```
corr = df.where(df>0.7).stack()
print(corr)

A  A    1.0
   B    0.8
B  A    0.8
   B    1.0
C  C    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Then to get the corresponding indices:

```
corr.index.tolist()

[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C')]
```

And most of the time I use `np.fill_diagonal` to ignore the diagonal of the correlation matrix:

```
np.fill_diagonal(corr.to_numpy(), 0)
corr = df.where(df>0.7).stack()
corr.index.tolist()

A  B    0.8
B  A    0.8
dtype: float64

[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A')]
```

Answer (score 2):

To find index where df == .8:

```
r, c = np.where(df==.8)
[i for i in zip(df.index[r], df.columns[c])]
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A')]
```

To find all indexes where df>.7:

```
r, c = np.where(df>.7)
[i for i in zip(df.index[r], df.columns[c])]
```

Output:

```
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C')]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.0, 0.8, 0.6],
                   'B':[0.8, 1.0, 0.1],
                   'C':[0.6, 0.1, 1.0]}, index = ['A', 'B', 'C'])

i = np.where(df >= 0.8)
```

gives you this result

```
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 2]))
```

to get back to your original labels you can use

```
x, y = i
pairs = list(zip(df.columns[x], df.index[y]))
```

which gets you to this list.

```
[('A', 'A'), ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('C', 'C')]
```

As `('A', 'B')` and `('B', 'A')` is redundant information in a correlation matrix you could filter these out (replaces the codeblock 2 above)

```
i_set = {tuple(sorted(tup)) for tup in zip(x, y)}
pairs = {(df.columns[x], df.columns[y]) for x,y in i_set}
```

And results in the following

```
{('A', 'A'), ('C', 'C'), ('B', 'B'), ('A', 'B')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply your condition directly on your dataframe, which will return a dataframe with True/False values.

```py
tmp_df = df > 0.7
```

now `tmp_df` will have True or False value in every cell, depends on the condition.
I'm not sure what you want to do next, but you can get filter row or columns based on true/false values (e.g print only true values and etc)